# There is no settings just Default settings - PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to learn flask and python, I followed a tutorial :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Welcome to Python Flask App!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

I went to File, I can't see Settings, only Default settings.
http://s24.postimg.org/j1sj5q86d/Screen_Shot_2015_10_16_at_7_33_21_PM.png

from the Default settings, I can't see the name of my project, I added flask :
http://s7.postimg.org/a6vx6n317/Screen_Shot_2015_10_16_at_7_36_35_PM.png

flask and Flask in the import are underlined red.
when I try to run it, I got :

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3 /Users/majid/PycharmProjects/flaskMysql/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/majid/PycharmProjects/flaskMysql/hello.py", line 1, in 
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which OS are you using? Seems like you are using Mac, so for that -> 
1) Click Pycharm on top left.
2) Click Preferences.
3) Click Project: %Project_Name%
4) Select Project Interpreter

Now you are in the settings, where you can choose the interpreter and the libraries which you want to work with, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this tip, now I can see project name, then I tried to add flask, but got an error :  http://s13.postimg.org/3v8c0xtl3/Screen_Shot_2015_10_16_at_8_23_09_PM.png

Comment: Can you try installing against a different version of python interpreter? Looks like the pip version is not correct, try running the flask installation from the terminal. This will install it against the default python which your system is using.

Comment: In order to further simplify your work, you can use Python 2.7 which works perfectly with all the libraries. Also for making it more simpler to work with different library dependencies, try working with Anaconda-Python interpreter which comes with most of the libraries and the setup of Flask works perfectly with it without any hassles.